# How to access a web application with a domain in a local network

Tags: networking, apache2, hostname, hosts

Under my network, I have setup an `Ubuntu Server 16.04`, which I have deployed some web applications which are accessible in the browser from `http://192.168.0.4/myapplication`.

What, I want is to access `myapplication` **in my local network only** with a shorter url like `http://srv/myapplication`

One approach is to edit the hosts in my computer and add the line

```
192.168.0.4 srv
```

where it works.
However, I want to ask if there is an another way to do this, without editing the host file in my computer (because then, I will have to edit the hosts file from all Computers).

I ask this, because under the same network there is another Server with `Windows Server 2008` operating system, where I have deployed some web applications there too and I access them by `http://myserver:8080/myApp` without adding the `192.168.0.3 myserver` in the host file!

The host file in my Ubuntu server currently is:

```
27.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.4     srv

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some points to your case:

1. We can suppose that your Ubuntu server has the correct hostname set on, right? If yes, the other computers can *ping* this server by the name?
2. Also, we can suppose that your web server that listens to the connections are configured to listen by name also, right?
3. If first two question were positive, you can take a look in your internal DNS server to make this resolution properly to your entire network.

Windows machines make use of one feature called NetBIOS ([more details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS)), that can resolve internal names by itself, and Linux machines, usually, don't have this feature, but it's possible to implement. You can read this topic also that they discussed it: https://serverfault.com/questions/352305/why-can-windows-machines-resolve-local-names-when-linux-cant

Cheers,
Vinícius